# Replace string containing a double quote

Tags: c#, string, replace

I feel like this should be pretty simple, but I'm struggling with it.  If I have a string that contains a double quote and I want to strip out that string, how would I go about doing that?

If I have this text:

```
The quick "brown" fox jumps over the "lazy" dog
```

I would think using this:

```
 .Replace("The quick \"brown\" fox jumps over the \"lazy\" dog", "");
```

but it doesn't seem to be recognizing the string with the double quotes.  All the searches I've come up with seem to want to replace the quotes themselves, not a string containing quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is. I just ran your sample code in LINQPad and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm doing something else wrong.  This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.  The string I have is pretty big and there's a Javascript function I'm trying to strip and it's not recognizing it.

Comment: Are you assigning the result of Replace to a new string or expecting it to modify the existing string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want is to simply strip out the quotes themselves, use this:

```
var input = "The quick \"brown\" fox jumps over the \"lazy\" dog";
var output = input.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
// output == "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

If you want to strip out the quotes *and* the text between the quotes, you will need to use a [`RegEx.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx), like this:

```
var input = "The quick \"brown\" fox jumps over the \"lazy\" dog";
var output = RegEx.Replace(input, "\"[^\"]*\"", string.Empty);
// output == "The quick  fox jumps over the  dog"
```

Comment: I think the op wants to replace the text which contains quotations, with an empty string.  This just removes the quotes

Comment: RegEx.Replace is a good idea, but a simple string.Replace should have worked too.  Hope it solves the op's problem :)

Comment: How would a simple String.Replace work? Unless he knows the EXACT quoted phrase to search for, a Regex is the way to go.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the string itself I was trying to replace, not the replace function.  Sorry about that!

Comment: The op's question was to replace the entire string, but seems like the op just wanted to replace the quoted text. @krisB update your question to better reflect what you are asking - to make it useful for others in the future